# ¿cómo uno un items separados en uno sólo y que se guarden caracteres específicos en una nueva lista?

Tags: python, lista

es que tengo una lista con objetos por separados y lo quiero unir pero no sé cómo.

Digamos que tengo ésta lista:

```
lista= ["1","2","3","2","3","1","3","2","2","1","2","2","3"]
```

y así como quiero que salga.

```
print(lista1)
1232313221223
```

ya teniendo esa lista nueva pegada, quisiera que automáticamente en otra lista se cree partes de "1" a "3"

```
lista_new = ["123","13","1223"]
```

pero de todo lo que me sale en las paginas nada me sirve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí te dejo la respuesta completa con explicaciones en los comentarios:

```
lista= ["1","2","3","2","3","1","3","2","2","1","2","2","3"]

ones = list()  # Variable para guardar la posición de todos los 1s
threes = list()  # Variable para guardar la posición de todos los 3s

result = "".join(lista)  # Uno todos los elementos de la lista en result

print(result)

for i, valor in enumerate(lista):  # Para cada valor de lista, crea un indice (i) empezando en 0
    if valor == '1':  # Si el valor es 1, guardo el índice donde lo encontré en ones
        ones.append(i)
    elif valor == '3':  # Si el valor es 3 y tengo más unos que treses:
        if len(ones) > len(threes):  # Tiene que hacerse así porque en la lista que pones hay más 3 que 1
            threes.append(i+1)  # Añado el +1 para incluir el 3 luego al imprimir
# print(ones, threes)

lista_new = []
for x in range(len(ones)):  # Hago un for de 0 a la longitud de la lista de 1s
    # La lista de 3s debería ser igual de larga
    lista_new.append("".join(lista[ones[x]:threes[x]]))  # Hago un join para obtener el string
    # Para cada "1" añado un slice de lista[posicionDelUno:posicionDelTres]

print(lista_new)
```

El resultado es exactamente el buscado: `['123', '13', '1223']`

Comment: ERES UN PINCHE DIOS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
GRACIAS!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: es por alguna razón me salta lista fuera de rango y no entiendo por qué en "lista_new", ¿hay alguna forma de contactarte para que puedas ver mi codigo? si no te molesta, claramente.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que tu pregunta se soluciona sabiendo utilizar funciones predefinidas de Python y saber utilizar [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

```py
import re
import string

def find_matches(list):
    return re.findall(r'12*3',string.join(list,""))

lista= ["1","2","3","2","3","1","3","2","2","1","2","2","3"]
print(find_matches(lista))
```

lo que hace `string.join` es que une todos los elementos de la lista dada un separador, como no queremos ninguna cadena de texto que los separe, solo ponemos la cadena vacía (`""`). La documentación `re.findall` se encuentra [aquí](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: muchísimas gracias, sí, justo después de hacer mi pregunta me respondí a mi mismo post cómo se unían las listas xd

Comment: Repasa más sobre expresiones regulares, son de mucha ayuda y hacen que el código se mas conciso y declarativo

Answer (score 0):

aaaaaaaah, descubrí que con .join(lista) me permite unir todos mis items <3

```
lista= ["1","2","3","2","3","1","3","2","2","1","2","2","3"]
x= "".join(lista)
print(x)
```

output

```
1232313221223
```

Pero sigo sin saber cómo resolver mi segunda pregunta...